# Filtering list of tuples based on the availability of a member in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I want to filter a list of tuples like `[(1,22,1),(5,1,8),(8,3,4),(7,5,6)]` using a list like `[1,7]` which would eventually give me the result `[(1,22,1),(5,1,8),(7,5,6)]`; since `(8,3,4)` does not have either `1` or `7`, it is eliminated.

I can write a comprehensive function for this. But I am looking for a short list comprehension if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> tup_list = [(1,22,1),(5,1,8),(8,3,4),(7,5,6)]
>>> filter_list = [1,7]
>>> [tup for tup in tup_list if any(i in tup for i in filter_list)]
[(1, 22, 1), (5, 1, 8), (7, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

try with this one :

```
items = [(1,22,1),(5,1,8),(8,3,4),(7,5,6)]
result = [ item for item in items if (set([1,7]) & set(item))]

>>> [(1, 22, 1), (5, 1, 8), (7, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: This has a certain elegance, but unfortunately I don't think this is a situation where `set`s result in a better performing solution. You can factor out the `set([1, 7])` but you have to do the intersection and `set(item)` every time, and the intersection doesn't short-circuit, unlike `any()`.

Comment: @agf : in term of performance, I agree, I think the any() solution is better, but as the OP was looking for a 'short' list comprehension, i'm not so far ;)